# CASE WHEN not working for some values with incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do a case when update statement but I keep getting a Incorrect syntax near '‭'. error. I don't get it because the second query below runs just fine but the first one doesn't. Only difference is I am setting `memrvam` to 1.24 instead 8.48.

```
UPDATE a
SET memslam = CASE detseqno
                 WHEN 1923 THEN 338.63
                 WHEN 43 THEN 355.56
              END,
    memrvam = CASE detseqno
                 WHEN 1923 THEN ‭8.48‬
                 WHEN 43 THEN 8.89
              END
FROM slst1consl a
LEFT JOIN wprsbatchxref b ON b.batchnum = a.batchid
                          AND b.recdate = a.recdt
                          AND b.supplier_date = a.supdt
WHERE b.batch_id IN(2058708, 2058709)
  AND memid = 922269
  AND detseqno IN (1043, 43);

UPDATE a
SET memslam = CASE detseqno
                 WHEN 1923 THEN 338.63
                 WHEN 43 THEN 355.56
              END,
    memrvam = CASE detseqno
                 WHEN 1923 THEN 1.24
                 WHEN 43 THEN 8.89
              END
FROM slst1consl a
LEFT JOIN wprsbatchxref b ON b.batchnum = a.batchid
                          AND b.recdate = a.recdt
                          AND b.supplier_date = a.supdt
WHERE b.batch_id IN (2058708, 2058709)
  AND memid = 922269
  AND detseqno IN (1043, 43);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hidden special characters there:

```
                THEN 8.48
```

When copying this line to my editor I see

```
                THEN ?8.48?
```

So, just remove the line and write it anew.

Comment: I'm glad I saved you from doing so :D